# mysql returning parent row only when looking at child rows

Tags: mysql

I have a parent table with columns:

```
id, valid
```

And a child table with columns:

```
parent_id, code, value
```

I want to find all parent rows that have "valid" set to 1 OR one of the child rows (with a particular code) has a value set to 1. Eg:

```
SELECT parent.id FROM parent,child where valid = 1 OR 
(child.code = 55 AND child.value = 1) and parent.id = child.parent_id;
```

But the above, in the case where valid = 1, returns N rows, one per child. This makes sense, since the OR part doesn't come into play and so i get a row back for each child row.

Since i'm only looking for the id, i can do distinct(parent.id); but is there a better way to do this sort of thing?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  parent.id
FROM    parent
WHERE   valid = 1
        OR EXISTS (
           SELECT 0 
           FROM   child 
           WHERE  child.value = 1 
                   AND child.parent_id = parent.id
        )
```

The SELECT 0 part is irrelevant. EXISTS only cares if the subquery returns any rows.

You could also...

```
SELECT  parent.id
FROM    parent
WHERE   valid = 1
        OR parent.id IN (
           SELECT child.parent_id 
           FROM   child 
           WHERE  child.value = 1 
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the group by keyword and group by parent.id

```
SELECT parent.id FROM parent,child where valid = 1 OR 
(child.code = 55 AND child.value = 1) and parent.id = child.parent_id GROUP BY parent.id;
```